# Trying to normalize a mysql database for call center

Tags: mysql, database, normalization

I recently just got a job at a call center and they have asked me to make their database more efficient and capable of storing and retrieving their information quickly. I get to build a completely new database for them. The problem is that im not that great at sql quiet yet. But if you could take a look at the picture could you help point me into the right direction or give a few tips. All the data of business and customer info is all stored in one big table with like around 40 columns. Im sure there is a way to normalize this data. Thanks ahead of time.
[image: Business & Customer information database]

Comment: Agree with @eggyal but will offer this quick one: I would break out the company name and all columns that define it - put a company id in this table and the new table with the company info - the id will be the pk to do JOINs on. Once you've created that new table you can populate it with the info in this table, then remove those columns from this table. Again, as stated by our 1st responder - that's for you to do or admit to the boss he/she needs to hire a trained db pro to do. Good luck.

Comment: Please reference [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking.  When you are ready to ask: 1. post the structure of each table you're asking about 2. post your code; with the proper format 3. please remove ***all*** fluff.  Read more about fluff [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough about your data to know for sure what *isn't* normalized right now.

The purpose of normalization is to make sure there's never a case where the same value is stored in two different places in the database.

So, if a particular company might have 10 leads, and each of those leads would have the same `company_name` and `employee_size` and `sales_volume` then there's a problem: each one of the 10 leads could potentially have different values there. One is "Company A", another "company A", another "Company A.", etc.

Instead, you should have a `company` table with those values, and a foreign key from your `lead` to that `company`. Now it's fine to have lots of leads with the same company because they're all referring to the same underlying `company` data.

Only you know which values in your data set might be repeatable and thus which to eliminate.